# Links on mouse hover event in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for menu (vertical) which shows sub menu on mouse hover event. the sub menu should exactly come at the right side of selected main menu list.

I came up to main menu with ng repeat by following snippets.

```
<head>
     <title>Links on Hover AngularJS</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="LinksController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leftlinks.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div id='content' ng-app='leftlinks' ng-controller='LinksController'>
        <ul type='none'>
            <li ng-repeat="link in links"><a href="#" class="leftlinks">{{link}}</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</body>
</html>



app.controller("LinksController", function($scope){
    $scope.links = ['link1','link2','link3','link4'];   
});
```

Could someone please take me forward in using ng-mouseenter and leave events. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<ANY
      ng-mouseenter="">
    ...
    </ANY>



<button ng-mouseenter="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment (when mouse enters)
</button>
count: {{count}}
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter

Comment: Thanks for the response Manikanta. Could you please share any example. I tried many times but no luck..:(